# socket exception while downloading files from android

Tags: android, sockets, download

I am using the below code to download zip file in android.code works fine ,but sometimes download fails and throws socket exception. especially while Internet connection is slow(i guess).i have also posted the screen shots of logcat error message.

int count;

```
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        //Log.e("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + "="+lenghtOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(StorezipFileLocation);

        byte data[] = new byte[lenghtOfFile];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += c![enter image description here][1]ount;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`connection reset by peer` usually means that you are talking to a peer wich think that the connection has already been closed. What I don't understand is why it happens when closing a `FileOutputStream`.

Besides, the exception does not happen in your code but in the finalizer. Is it possible that when something goes wrong, you catch the exception in an upper level and leave the connection and file opened ? The abandonned connection is closed by the finalyser, but it's too late.

I am not sure that it will solves the problem but it is a good practice to use a  `finally` clause to be sure that files and connections are properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

The log doesn't say where the crash occurs in your code. Isn't there some more info that doesn't appear in your screenshot?

It seems that it fails on the close method of your file input stream.
You could simply surround the calls to close() with a try catch block and set your stream to null (if it failed on closing)

Comment: If the error occurs when executing the "close()" line, then your download should be finished. Have you tried just catching the exeption? Otherwise, do you know where the error occurs? when waiting for data?